# Xcode - Export Gif with alpha into Video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, gif

What i'm trying to do is to create a video with some gif over it. So i have the background video (mp4) and then i have some gif downloaded from giphy. To export a final video, i need to convert the gifs into mp4 and then insert them over my background video.

The problem is that when i'm converting a gif with a trasparent background like this one, results that the gif's transparent background become a black background:

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/stickers/seasons-3ohhwExYXg3q8oC26Q)

I know that the problem is about the ios coder/decoder default that use h264 as video codec, and this codec doesn't support alpha channel.

Do you have any ideas on how implement this?

Thanks

Comment: I want to convert a gif into a video, and I have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: No, apparently the default codec of iOS doesn't support the alpha channel